# Scala function/method parametrized return type

Tags: scala, generics, methods, types, return

I have just come up with something that I don't understand. I'm trying to return a parametrized type from a method, the code is the following (working example):

```
trait Expression

case class ExpImp1() extends Expression
case class ExpImp2() extends Expression

object Main {

  private def testParametrizedTypes[T](): T = {
    ExpImp1()
  }

  private def testWrappedParametrizedTypes[T <: Expression](): Option[T] = {
    Some(new ExpImp1())
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  }

}
```

but when I compile this code, the compiler says (the IDE warns me about the same error in both functions):

```
Error:(10, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : ExpImp1
 required: T
    ExpImp1()
           ^
```

I think that the code showed previously should work. In the first method I'm returning a type T and T has no constraint. The compiler error also occurs in the second method, but the parametrized type conforms to the returned object type too.

Also, I wrote a code a few weeks ago that looked like that that compiled with no problems (this is not a working example as this code is part of a Play Framework project):

```
class CanBeAuthenticatedRequest[A](val request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class UnauthenticatedRequest[A](override val request: Request[A]) extends CanBeAuthenticatedRequest(request)

class AuthenticatedRequest[A](val user: String, override val request: Request[A]) extends CanBeAuthenticatedRequest[A](request)

object CanBeAuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[CanBeAuthenticatedRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A]...
  }

  object Fold {

    private def partialFunctionBuilder[T](authenticated: (AuthenticatedRequest[_]) => T)
                                         (unauthenticated: (UnauthenticatedRequest[_]) => T):
    PartialFunction[CanBeAuthenticatedRequest[_], T] = {
      case ar: AuthenticatedRequest[_] => authenticated(ar)
      case ur: UnauthenticatedRequest[_] => unauthenticated(ur)
    }

    def apply[T](request: CanBeAuthenticatedRequest[_])
               (authenticated: (AuthenticatedRequest[_]) => T)
               (unauthenticated: (UnauthenticatedRequest[_]) => T): T = {
      partialFunctionBuilder(authenticated)(unauthenticated)(request)
    }

  }

}
```

As you can see, I successfully defined the function "partialFunctionBuilder" and I'm using it.

"partialFunctionBuilder" follows the same pattern, returning a type that is parametrized with "T". I don't see what's the difference between the code I showed first and the Play Framework code. Removing "<: Expression" from the "testWrappedParametrizedTypes" keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: The return type `testParametrizedTypes ` is T. But you are returning a **value** of type `ExpImp1 `. The compiler has to complain. Why are you confused about that?

Comment: @I.K. because ExpImp1 is a subtype of Expression, isn't it? See the second method "testWrappedParametrizedTypes"

Comment: Yes that's right, but how does that relate to the type parameter **T**? The compiler cannot infer any relationship so it has to complain.

Comment: @I.K. And why the compiler does not complain in the Play Framework example?

Comment: Because it's not returning a type parameter, it's returning a type of PartialFunction. That's different.

Comment: @I.K. in "testWrappedParametrizedTypes" I'm returning an Option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89965/discussion-between-i-k-and-vicaba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function has a type parameter with some constraints, it should be possible to call it with any parameter, satisfying those constraints. So given the definitions it should be possible to call `testParametrizedTypes[String]()` or `testWrappedParametrizedTypes[ExpImpl2]()`. But because in both cases you return a fixed type `ExpImpl1`, or `Option[ExpImpl1]`, there is a type mismatch.

And in the Play example it *is* possible to call `partialFunctionBuilder`, with any type `T`, if you pass it the correct functions, which return that type `T`.

Comment: See another relevant example here: https://github.com/feynmanliang/cats-logo/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/feynmanliang/logo/InterpretOpt.scala#L18; This repo is for this blog post: http://blog.scalac.io/2016/06/02/overview-of-free-monad-in-cats.html